# Why is an Octet Complete Cation more stable than a Resonance Stabilized Cation?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Our instructor has lately been teaching us about different types of cations namely-Classical, Non-Classical, Resonance stabilized (**R.S.C**) & Octet complete cation (**O.C.C**) & how O.C.C is more stable than a R.S.C .

One thing I did not get isn't donating lone pair like in the below given example too is resonance ,so how come these two phenomena are any different?

 [image] (R.S.C)
[image](O.C.C)
& also, why is the latter structure more stable ?